# Inserting Keynote slides into a Pages document

Tags: automation, applescript, iwork-pages, iwork-keynote

I have a number of training documents which are formed from a word processor file and a slideshow. I'd like to be able to keep them together, ideally by inserting the slides from Keynote into Pages. Is there any way of doing this quickly? So far I have tried Applescript with little success. I can drag and drop the slides one at a time but it is a bit slow, and I've tried turning the slideshow into and dragging it into Pages but this only pulls in the first slide. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect because the slides are slightly off centre, but it works well enough for me. Just run the following Applescript:

```
tell application "Keynote"
    set theNumberOfSlides to count of slides in slideshow 1
end tell

repeat with i from 1 to theNumberOfSlides
    tell application "Keynote"
        activate
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {command down}
    end tell

    tell application "Pages"
        activate
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using {command down}
    end tell

    tell application "Keynote"
        activate
        tell application "System Events" to key code 125
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

My best recommendation is that you export the keynote slides into individual JPEGs.
Then they are easily re-sized and are lighter when imported into the other documents.

Comment: The question was, “Is there any way of doing this quickly?”  How does your recommendation answer the question?